# How does the remote data source work in Jquery Mobile autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I am reading this page http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autocomplete-remote/ and there seems to be no documentation on how the remote data source is suppose to look like or work.

In that page you can see the JS example for the remote data source is `http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity` but going to that URL doesn't reveal anything.

Does anyone know how it's suppose to be structured so that in works with the autocomplete page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is returned in JSON as an array. In the example of the documentation, if you have a look at the JS code:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp"
...
.then(function(response) {  // <-- this expects response as a JSON object
$.each(response,function(i,val){  // <-- each iterates over the array, i is the index, val is the value
    html+="<li>"+val+"</li>"; //<-- creates the HTML for the autocomplete

})
```

In fact, you can use Google Developer Tools on Chrome to see the response. In the example, if you write 'Ale' you get:

```
jQuery1102023577826283872128_1446566971852(["Aledo, IL, United States","Aledo, MU, Spain","Aledo, TX, United States","Aleknagik, AK, United States","Aleppo, HL, Syria","Aleppo, PA, United States","Alert, NT, Canada","alesund, MR, Norway","Alex, OK, United States","Alexander City, AL, United States","Alexander, AR, United States","Alexander, IA, United States","Alexander, IL, United States","Alexander, KS, United States","Alexander, NC, United States","Alexander, ND, United States","Alexander, NY, United States","Alexandra Headland, QL, Australia","Alexandra Hills, QL, Australia","Alexandra, GT, South Africa"]);
```

You can try the URL of the example passing a query as an argument using the variable `q`:

```
http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?q=abe
```

Comment: Sorry, I am having issues replicating this, can you check out this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834280/cant-replicate-jquery-mobile-autocomplete-demo