# Can't replicate Jquery Mobile Autocomplete demo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I am trying to replicate this demo with my own remote data source:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autocomplete-remote/

My HTML page is exactly the same as the demo with one difference:

`url: "http://localhost/sample.php",`

And here's my dummy remote data source `sample.php`

```
<?php

$a = array('apple', 'mango');

echo json_encode($a);
```

What could be missing here? Since my dummy data is just a simple array, I am expecting that it will autocomplete with `"apple", "mango"` but nothing appears.

**Edit:** I tried the following, still doesn't work:

```
<?php

$a = array("apple", "mango");

header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($a).');';
```

Comment: do you use firebug or something similar? If so does the console say anything?

Comment: @MartinE. It appears to be responding okay: http://i.imgur.com/WnClii8.png

Comment: header("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: @ojovirtual tried but didn't work

Comment: are you using both script on same domain ?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes in `localhost` only for now

Comment: You don't need the same domain for JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "View source" actually lies. There's a missing line in HTML as next JS `$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#myPage", function() {` expects `#myPage`. Thus, HTML should look this way:

```
<body>
    <!-- this div was missing --> 
    <div data-role="page"  id="myPage">
        <h3>Cities worldwide</h3>
        <p>After you enter <strong>at least three characters</strong> the autocomplete function will show all possible matches.</p>
        <form class="ui-filterable">
            <input id="autocomplete-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Find a city...">
        </form>
        <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-input="#autocomplete-input"></ul>  
    </div>
</body>
```

So if you add that missing div `<div data-role="page" id="myPage">` and use next php code, then everything will work fine:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $json = json_encode(['apple', 'mango']);
    echo "$callback($json);";
?>
```

Just in case, these are 2 files I used in my test:

- http://pastebin.com/7p4b4mmB
- http://pastebin.com/svPYtHqP (url, pointing to PHP, should be replaced)

Comment: Your answer has merit but I also have the missing line in my test page but you know what, I found the issue: Including jqm's CSS is causing it! `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />` Try to include that line in your test page and it won't work but apparently it works with their demo PHP. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Still works - even with including this CSS. You can easily download my HTML and try it (even w/o localhost) - just in the browser. The URL there points to a free PHP fiddle-like service: `http://main.xfiddle.com/code_94010918.php?callback=apple&q=123`

Comment: Hmm, I am testing it in your exact page. I get this with CSS: http://i.imgur.com/WFg7wmW.png and this without: http://i.imgur.com/dLvceAs.png

Comment: oh, I see what you mean: CSS does the trick with hiding. Try to enter "apple" instead of "test" or "mango".

Comment: *cuss word* yeah! that was just my problem after all this time. blew my head for days. I deserve the bounty! Kidding LOL